# How can I make a UIElement show after collapse in upper direction?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visibility, uielement

On my form, I have a `TextBlock` element that initially is collapsed. (`TextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`). When some error occurred, it should be shown. When I use `TextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Show`, all the controls that are situated under the `TextBlock`, are getting down.

Question: How to dock all the elements that are situated under this `TextBlock` in such a way that in case when the `TextBlock` is shown, to lift the upper elements?

Comment: When a control grows the Window or Page makes room the right and bottom.  I don't think there is a way to change that behavior.

Comment: There is, in a limited way, if you take advantage of vertical alignment

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is through strategic use of the `VerticalAlignment` property. Consider the following snippet. If this stackpanel is in a container where it has room to grow, it will grow upwards. When you toggle the visibility on the middle textblock, then, it will push the elements above it.

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <TextBlock>I shift upward</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed">Error message here</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>I stay put</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: But that mean leaving empty space to grow.   So now real estate is actually gained by the Collapsed.  Still +1.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I forgot about the default values of VerticalAlignment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your question is, but if you do not want the other controls to move when the `TextBlock` becomes visible then it should start with `Visibility.Hidden`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to keep the layout space for this TextBlock, I want to keep it collapsed.

Comment: Well I don't understand what it would look like to lift the upper elements as you say in your question.